# Will a Queueable Class run in series if it is recursive?

Tags: apex, trigger, api, httprequest, queueable-apex

I have a scenario where I need to call an API from a `trigger` that will update a few fields from the API.  The `trigger` is an `after insert` and is setup to avoid recursion with other triggers on the same object.

Currently I am having the problem of the API (I do not control it) not being able to handle request in parallel.  My current code takes an `after insert trigger`, fires the first apex class with `Queueable` Interface which checks for if my Oauth token is expired, if it is - request a new one from the API, if not proceed to fire the second `Queueable` class which makes the request in a loop to get the fields for each of the Salesforce records.  This is actually working until we start using alot of records which is necessary.  Even at 1000 records split up in batches of 50 via Dataloader it seems like those are too many requests for the API.

So to avoid the problem of having multiple `Queueable` calls that run in parallel, I was wondering if I should just chain the 2nd `Queueable` class to itself.   Would that hit the `Queueable` limit of depth.  Or is this just something that needs to be moved out of the `trigger` entirely?

Comment: a queueable that chains to another job of the same class is no different than a queueable that chains to a job of a different class

Comment: @cropredy I didn't think of it like that.  So it still wont work because each trigger execution will queue more records to hit the API endpoint

Comment: So your problem is that you have multiple users executing a trigger (hence, possibly in parallel) and each trigger kicks off queueable that ultimately invoke the remote API and the remote API can't handle parallel requests?

Comment: @cropredy no we have one user dataload in several thousand of the records at a time.  But the queueable classes are still executing in parallel, which is the problem

Comment: To single thread the queueables: take a look at the dan appleman advanced apex book 4th edition - chapter entitled "Going Asynchronous ".  You basically need to store the callout requests in a custom object that a monitor transaction reads from.  The book has sample code to do this.